# ggplot: geom_boxplot not ordering median values correctly on just one value

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, boxplot

I really hate to ask a question without a reproducible example, but there is too much data likely needed to be able to replicate the problem.  Instead I will show the code I have and am hoping that someone can point out an error.

I am creating a violin plot with geom_boxplot inside.  It works great, except one of the boxplots is showing a lower median value, even though it is ordered correctly on the graph (that is, the graph should be ordered by median value of y, and the violin plots are in that order, but the median line drawn in the boxplot shows the median as lower).  When I double check the median values independently, I get the correct median values in the violin order.  See picture of plot [image: here]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the median line drawn by geom_boxplot would have the wrong value drawn when the others are correct?  I am know this will be hard to diagnose without a reprex but I figured it was worth a shot.

```
my_data <- other_data %>% 
  mutate(my_x = fct_reorder(my_x, my_y, median))

my_max <- 20

# Create violin plot with a box plot within
p <- ggplot(my_data, aes(x = my_x, y = my_y, fill = my_x)) +
  geom_violin() + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1, color = "grey50", alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, my_max, 4),
                     limits = c(0, my_max),
                     expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size  = 10, face = "bold")) 
p
```

Comment: My guess is your `limits = c(0, my_max)`.  The way ggplot2 works is providing a limits vector within a scaling function removes the data outside of the limits.  You are better off by specifying an additional `coord_cartesian( ylim=c(0,my_max) )` and removing the limits statement within your `scale_y_continuous()` function.

Comment: No, no values go below zero.

Comment: The comment above acts more like a zoom feature versus a data filter.

Comment: statstew, you are on to something!  When I took out the whole scale_y_continuous the problem went away.  Why would that cause the issue?  Is it because the scale_y_continous is clipping the values above 20, and therefore calculating a lower median in the geom_boxplot function?  I would have thought that geom_boxplot would be using all of the data to calculate the median (even those values above 20)

Comment: Yes.  Applying the limits within a scale_x_y function actually acts as a data filter PRIOR to the plot being created.  So yes, by removing the values above 20 for the particular category would result the boxplot being created as having a lower median than its neighbors.  That result would've happened with any geom_xxx() function.

Comment: So helpful, much appreciated